# How does the comparator in d3.scan() work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm reading the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#scan) for d3.scan().

> Performs a linear scan of the specified iterable, returning the index
>   of the least element according to the specified comparator. If the
>   given iterable contains no comparable elements (i.e., the comparator
>   returns NaN when comparing each element to itself), returns undefined.
>   If comparator is not specified, it defaults to ascending. For example:

```
const array = [{foo: 42}, {foo: 91}];
d3.scan(array, (a, b) => a.foo - b.foo); // 0
d3.scan(array, (a, b) => b.foo - a.foo); // 1
```

> This function is similar to min, except it allows the use of a
>   comparator rather than an accessor and it returns the index instead of
>   the accessed value. See also bisect.

The first d3.scan() command says *"for the object called array, check if a.foo, 42, is the largest value"* and the second d3.scan() command says *"for the object called array, check if b.foo, 91, is the largest value"*, and then 0/1 is the TRUE/FALSE response.

Can I use it with larger arrays?

Is that the right way to understand the d3.scan() command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is a misunderstanding here about how d3.scan works, when you say *"and then 0/1 is the TRUE/FALSE response"*.

The `0` and `1` values are **not** `true` and `false`, they are just the **indices** of the element inside the array, according to your comparator. The very paragraph you copied has it:

> Performs a linear scan of the specified iterable, returning the **index** of the least element according to the specified comparator. (emphasis mine)

Also, `a` and `b` are not the first and second elements in the examples array (it's misleading, because the example array has just 2 elements): if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/scan.js)...

```
for (const value of values) {
    ++index;
    if (minIndex === undefined
        ? compare(value, value) === 0
        : compare(value, min) < 0) {
      min = value;
      minIndex = index;
    }
}
```

... you'll see that they are just the current element in the `for...of` loop and the last element that passed the comparator test.

Let's see that in a demo. Suppose this array:

```
 const array = [{foo: 42}, {foo: 91}, {foo: 32}, {foo: 256}, {foo: 17}, {foo: 8}];
```

As you can see, the highest `foo` value is the 4th element (index `3`). Check the console:

```js
const array = [{
  foo: 42
}, {
  foo: 91
}, {
  foo: 32
}, {
  foo: 256
}, {
  foo: 17
}, {
  foo: 8
}];

const index = d3.scan(array, (a, b) => b.foo - a.foo);
console.log(index)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Likewise, the smallest `foo` value is the last element (index `5`). Again, check the console:

```js
const array = [{
  foo: 42
}, {
  foo: 91
}, {
  foo: 32
}, {
  foo: 256
}, {
  foo: 17
}, {
  foo: 8
}];

const index = d3.scan(array, (a, b) => a.foo - b.foo);
console.log(index)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

That being said, this answers your first question (*"Can I use it with larger arrays?"*): yes, of course, that's exactly the purpose of d3.scan... I can quickly compare an array of two objects for a given property just by looking at it, I don't need d3.scan for that, but I cannot do the same with an array of 1000 elements.